# Filter array with for expression in scala throws wrong output, why?

Tags: scala

Trying to filter array with for expression. o/p Array(2, 4, 1)
I don't know why it is showing the wrong o/p. please help!

```
def filter_array(a: Int, lst: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = for(x<-lst;if x<a) yield lst(x) 
println(filter_array(3, Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0)).mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
```

Comment: What output are you expecting to see?

Comment: `yield list(x)` means you are not adding the values that passed the predicate, but rather the values at the indexes that passed the predicate so `lst(1) = 2`,  `lst(2) = 4` and  `lst(0) = 1` - If you follow best practices you can do this instead: `def filterLowerThan(a: Int)(data: List[Int]): List[Int] = data.filter(_ < a)`

Comment: I was expecting items less than 3 in an array that is 1,2,0 using for expression. It works with filter but I need to solve it without using filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use a for expression then this will do

```scala
def filter_array(a: Int, lst: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = for (x <- lst if x < a) yield x
println(filter_array(3, Array(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0)).mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))
```

If you don't need a for expression, this is simpler

```scala
def filter_array(a: Int, lst: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = lst.filter(_ < a)
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
for (x <- lst; if x < a) yield lst(x)
```

desugars to

```
lst.withFilter(x => x < a).map(x => lst.apply(x))
```

Note how Scala indexes sequence collections via `apply` method

```
lst.apply(x)
```

which is the reason for your wrong output: instead of yielding the element `x` you are yielding the element of `lst` at index `x`.